# Delay Newsletter Pop Up - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a magento template from templatemonster with an automatic newsletter pop up. The newsletter pops up immediately after page load. I would like to delay the pop up by 5 seconds. I am new to javascript but have found this code within the relevant magento folder:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                var newsPopup       = jQuery('#newsletterpopup');
                var newsPopupClose  = newsPopup.find('.close');
                var showNewsPopup = sessionStorage.getItem("showNewsPopup");

                if (showNewsPopup != '0') {
                    newsPopup.modal();
                };                  

                newsPopupClose.click(function(){
                    sessionStorage.setItem("showNewsPopup", '0');
                });
            });
```

Is this the correct place to be able to delay the pop up? What do I need to do to add a 5 second delay to the pop up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
 if (showNewsPopup != '0') {
     newsPopup.modal();
 };
```

to this:

```
 if (showNewsPopup != '0') {
     setTimeout(function(){
         newsPopup.modal();
     }, 5000);
 };
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was just about to reply myself as I had got the same solution working. Thanks for your help anyway